# Возникает null Pointer при передаче this

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Пытаюсь заинджектить в поле класса RxSocket в Presenter

```
@Inject
public RxSocket socket;

private AuthView view;

public AuthPresenter() {
    App.getComponent().inject(this); //Вот здесь возникает ошибка
    view = getViewState();
}
```

Вот так выглядит App:

```
public class App extends Application{

private static AppComponent component;

public static AppComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = buildComponent();
}

protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .modelModule(new ModelModule())
            .build();
}

}
```

Вот компонент

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ModelModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(AuthPresenter presenter);
}
```

Вот модуль:

```
@Module
public class ModelModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
RxSocket provideSocket(){
    IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
    options.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
    options.reconnection = false;
    options.forceNew = false;
    return new RxSocket(Constants.URL, options);
    }
}
```

И возникает вот такая ошибка:

```
2-11 17:19:15.300 3564-3564/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: ru.exodus.lorehub, PID: 3564
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.exodus.lorehub/ru.exodus.lorehub.ui.activities.AuthActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void ru.exodus.lorehub.other.di.AppComponent.inject(ru.exodus.lorehub.presentation.presenters.activities.AuthPresenter)' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void ru.exodus.lorehub.other.di.AppComponent.inject(ru.exodus.lorehub.presentation.presenters.activities.AuthPresenter)' on a null object reference
                                                 at ru.exodus.lorehub.presentation.presenters.activities.AuthPresenter.<init>(AuthPresenter.java:34)
                                                 at ru.exodus.lorehub.ui.activities.AuthActivity$$PresentersBinder$presenterBinder.providePresenter(AuthActivity$$PresentersBinder.java:24)
                                                 at ru.exodus.lorehub.ui.activities.AuthActivity$$PresentersBinder$presenterBinder.providePresenter(AuthActivity$$PresentersBinder.java:12)
                                                 at com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpProcessor.getMvpPresenter(MvpProcessor.java:52)
                                                 at com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpProcessor.getMvpPresenters(MvpProcessor.java:102)
                                                 at com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpDelegate.onCreate(MvpDelegate.java:105)
                                                 at com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpActivity.onCreate(MvpActivity.java:21)
                                                 at ru.exodus.lorehub.ui.activities.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:32)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Comment: Наверное вы забыли указать ваш `App` класс в манифесте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Он действительно не прописан, можете в ответе написать, как его правильно прописать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас не вызываете `onCreate` метод, где вы инициализируете `AppComponent` ибо ваш класс не указан в качестве класса приложения в манифесте. Надо прописать так:

(Если класс `App` лежит в пакете `ru.stackoverflow.android`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.stackoverflow.android">

    <application
        android:name="ru.stackoverflow.android.MyApplication"
```